# iptables error in use extensions

Tags: iptables

I am struggling with this feature of iptable :

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
```

It does not work, I searched in the netfilter documentation and OpernWRT as well but I did not find any help from these, I catch this error message:

```
iptables v1.4.6: Couldn't load match `socket':File not found
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you positive it makes sense to look for an associated socket in the `PREROUTING` chain of the `mangle` table?

Comment: Yes I am, see http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt

Comment: Excellent. Did you see this notice? _enable `NETFILTER_TPROXY`, the `socket` match and the `TPROXY` target in
 your kernel config. You will need policy routing too, so be sure to enable that as well._

Comment: No, did you read this notice in the link I wrote before ? How can I do that in the kernel config ? I am a newbye in this type of problem. Under make menuconfig --> .. --> iptables  I can't see NETFILTER. :-(

Comment: I catch the point, thanks a lot!

Comment: From within `make menuconfig`, you can use `/` to search for config items; search for `TPROXY`, `SOCKET`, and `MULTIPLE_TABLES` for the different configuration options.

Answer (score 1):

File not found? You don't have libxt_socket.so installed in the plugin directory. Given that it is OpenWRT, where extensions are split into many distro-level packages, chances are you did not install the ipkg/opkg package that contains the socket extensions.

Edit: This does not have anything to do with the kernel config. If the kernel module was missing, the error would be:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to enable NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_SOCKET option in kernel config,

config NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_SOCKET

```
    tristate '"socket" match support (EXPERIMENTAL)'
    depends on EXPERIMENTAL
    depends on NETFILTER_TPROXY
    depends on NETFILTER_XTABLES
    depends on NETFILTER_ADVANCED
    depends on !NF_CONNTRACK || NF_CONNTRACK
    select NF_DEFRAG_IPV4
    help
      This option adds a `socket' match, which can be used to match
      packets for which a TCP or UDP socket lookup finds a valid socket.
      It can be used in combination with the MARK target and policy
      routing to implement full featured non-locally bound sockets.

      To compile it as a module, choose M here.  If unsure, say N.
```